# how to insert multi-row in mysql if it's not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to insert multi-row at same time.
but I want to ignore each one that already in table.
I just make query but It had a syntax problem.
Any one can help me to solve it?
here is my sql query:

```
INSERT INTO `targetmediaid` (`pageid`, `targetpageid`, `mediaid`) 
SELECT "4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121716250721765_5633144318"  UNION 
SELECT "4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121605403655131_5633144318"  UNION 
SELECT "4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121513523117304_5633144318"  UNION 
SELECT "4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121293112402936_5633144318"  UNION 
SELECT "4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121119770209275_5633144318"  UNION 
SELECT "4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121021170710600_5633144318"  UNION 
SELECT "4578583556", "5633144318", "1544120871450810242_5633144318"  UNION 
SELECT "4578583556", "5633144318", "1542556083004139499_5633144318"  as t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   ( SELECT `pageid`, `targetpageid`, `mediaid` 
       FROM `targetmediaid` 
      WHERE `mediaid` 
         IN  ("1544121716250721765_5633144318" , 
              "1544121605403655131_5633144318" , 
              "1544121513523117304_5633144318" , 
              "1544121293112402936_5633144318" , 
              "1544121119770209275_5633144318" , 
              "1544121021170710600_5633144318" , 
              "1544120871450810242_5633144318" , 
              "1542556083004139499_5633144318" 
             )
```

Comment: personal advice: try to format your SQL-statements - 
have a look at [SQL style guide](http://www.sqlstyle.guide/)
 - proper formated SQL statements make trouble shooting & all futher changes easier for you and your fellows - i tried to format the code in your question a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique index on `pageid`, `targetpageid`, `mediaid` columns and use INSERT IGNORE statement.
`INSERT IGNORE INTO targetmediaid (pageid, targetpageid, mediaid) VALUES ("4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121716250721765_5633144318"), ("4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121605403655131_5633144318"),("4578583556", "5633144318", "1544121513523117304_5633144318")`..... and so on.